# Sorting dates differently based on true/false flag

Tags: mysql, sorting

I am trying to sort a date column based on whether the paid flag is true or false. If the paid flag is false (unpaid) I want the oldest to show up first. If the paid flag is true I want the newest to show up first.

Current Query:

```
SELECT due_date, date_paid, 
    IF(i.date_paid IS NULL, 0, 1) AS paid_flag 
FROM tc_vendorInvoices 
ORDER BY paid_flag, 
        CASE WHEN paid_flag = 0 THEN due_date END ASC, 
        CASE WHEN paid_flag = 0 THEN due_date END DESC 
LIMIT 0, 50
```

This only sorts the paid flags, and due date is ASC:

```
due_date   |    date_paid     |  paid_flag
2020-09-28          NULL             0
2020-09-29          NULL             0
2020-10-01          NULL             0
2020-09-14      2020-09-14           1 
2020-09-29      2020-09-29           1
2020-10-05      2020-10-05           1
```

It needs to sort like this:

```
due_date   |    date_paid     |  paid_flag
2020-09-28          NULL              0
2020-09-29          NULL              0
2020-10-01          NULL              0
2020-10-05      2020-10-05            1
2020-09-29      2020-09-29            1
2020-09-14      2020-09-14            1
```

Comment: Never use evil `SELECT  *`

Comment: @Strawberry I actually am not, that was just for demo purposes.

Comment: Edit your question accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A trick with the boolean flag `paid_flag` and the function [`to_seconds()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_to-seconds) will do it:

```
order by paid_flag,
         ((not paid_flag) - paid_flag) * to_seconds(due_date)
```

When `paid_flag` is `0`, then `((not paid_flag) - paid_flag)` returns `1` so the sorting is ascending.
When `paid_flag` is `1`, then `((not paid_flag) - paid_flag)` returns `-1` so the sorting is done by `-to_seconds(due_date)` which is descending.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=3058e4e9520c67f6062b75b2de1e6dff).
Results:

```
> due_date   | date_paid  | paid_flag
> :----------| :--------- | --------:
> 2020-09-28 | null       |         0
> 2020-09-29 | null       |         0
> 2020-10-01 | null       |         0
> 2020-10-05 | 2020-10-05 |         1
> 2020-09-29 | 2020-09-29 |         1
> 2020-09-14 | 2020-09-14 |         1
```

Comment: I had to change 'to_seconds' to 'UNIX_TIMESTAMP', but it did work.

Answer (score 0):

We can't move the ASC or DESC inside an expression,  it's part of the ORDER BY clause.  So a construct like this is okay:

```
ORDER  
   BY fee
    , fi    DESC
    , fo    ASC
```

We can use expressions to conditionally return a value, and then sort on that expression.  The trick is to return a fixed value for the rows we don't want to be sorted.

Something like this:

```
ORDER BY paid_flag
       , CASE paid_flag WHEN 0 THEN due_date ELSE NULL     END  ASC
       , CASE paid_flag WHEN 0 THEN NULL     ELSE due_date END  DESC
```

There are other approaches; this one just happens to closely mimic the approach it looks like the original was attempting.